# how do I conditionally subtract in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do the following with knowing that column A and B are data and C is the result:

```
A   B    C  

1   5  (B1-A1)=4  

2   3  (B2-A1)=2  

3   5  (B3-A1)=4  

4   7  (B4-A2)=5

5   4  (B5-A2)=3

6   9  (B6-A2)=7
    .  
    .  
    .  
    .
```

How do I do this automatically in Excel or in Excel Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub sequence()

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
i = 2
j = 2

For i = 2 To 25 Step 3

Cells(i, 3) = Cells(i, 2) - Cells(j, 1)
Cells(i + 1, 3) = Cells(i + 1, 2) - Cells(j, 1)
Cells(i + 2, 3) = Cells(i + 2, 2) - Cells(j, 1)
j = j + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Here is the VBA code that solves.

You must define the range in **for loop**, currently it is set from **2nd Row to 25th Row**.

Answer (score 0):

```
A       B         C
1       4       =B2-A2
1       2       =B3-A3
1       3       =B4-A4
=A2+1   5       =B5-A5
=A3+1   6       =B6-A6
=A4+1   7       =B7-A7
=A5+1   6       =B8-A8
=A6+1   7       =B9-A9
=A7+1   9       =B10-A10
```

You can initiate your first 3 rows with **1**  and then just add **1 in the 4th row column A**; drag the formula down. Subsequently, you may then subtract Column B from Column A.

The only drawback is that your **column A** will not be a sequence incrementing by 1 every step instead a sequence stepping by 1 on every fourth occasion.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did not mention that column A is not incremented,column A and B are raw data(not adjustable) I might used a bad example by using data in serial form,forget about the shape of the data in column A, my question is how do you subtract 3 data from column B from only one datum from column A as I mentioned in the question and do that for 1072 rows in A and 362 rows in B? Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

OFFSET with ROW() is your friend for any repeating n-th row/column problem.

`=B1-OFFSET(A$1,ROUNDUP(ROW()/3,0)-1,0)`, copied down column C.

```
1   5   4
2   3   2
3   5   4
4   7   5
5   4   2
6   9   7
```

Comment: I tried this however, the A$1 does not move when i copy down the cells, but thank you very much for your effort, my question in answered.Regards

Comment: @user3449078 the A$1 is not meant to move when you copy down...if you tried it you would see it gives the correct results, as shown above.

Comment: Yes, you are correct , It got me wrong answers cuz I have headers for my columns,Data start from row 3. So, when I moved my data to start from row 1 , it works, Thank you very much for your help !!! Regards

Comment: @user3449078 ah, that makes sense. Glad it worked either way ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the $ in the function ($B5-$A1) and drag the cursor with the cell over the C column to the last element written.

Comment: I did that, it did not work !! Thank you anyway for your help.